# how to add scroll to div that have no fixed height

Tags: css, html, overflow

I have a div which I don't want to give fixed height.

I want this div to have a scroll in case the content is larger then the window,

I add this to my div:

```
overflow: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

but I still don't see the scroll if the content is bigger the the window.

Any thought on the same is appreciated.

Comment: give max-height and overflow:scroll and then try it. try this http://jsfiddle.net/PJbhH/

Answer (score 1):

You could use javascript to determine the height of the window and after that set the max-height css property like @Fags suggested.

```
<script>
$(function() {
  var $window = $(window);
  var setMaxHeight = function() {
    $('#div_id').css('max-height', $window.height());
  }
  $window.on('resize', setMaxHeight);
  setMaxHeight();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

`max-height:set from javascript` and `overflow-x:scroll;`

For Example

http://jsfiddle.net/PJbhH/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
max-height:400px;//some px value
overflow:auto;
```